# Systemctl services start and UFW ports allow script

Tags: bash, shell

I made a script to start something akin to a "session" in which I start services and open tcp and udp ports in the firewall in order to work with, for example, a full stack project, and stop and close the
corresponding services and ports once I'm done using them.

When I call the script, I place the services with the `-s` options and the ports with `-p`. After the `-s` option I input all the services in I want to start and then likewise with the ports. You can skip the services and/or the ports.

When I start the script, it starts the services via `systemctl start` and opens the ports via `ufw allow`. Then it pauses and awaits a key press after which it stops the services and closes the ports.

The services on my system are managed by Systemctl. The firewall software I use is Uncomplicated Firewall (UFW).

Usage: `./start -s service1 service2 -p port1 port2`

Example: `./start -s postgresql httpd -p WWW`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $EUID != 0 ]; then
    sudo "$0" "$@"
    exit $?
fi

flag=
services=()
ports=()

while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    case "$1" in
        -s) flag="SERVICE" ;;
        -p) flag="PORT" ;;
        *)
            case $flag in
                SERVICE) services+=($1) ;;
                PORT) ports+=($1) ;;
            esac
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done


# Starts the services and opens the ports
start() {
    for serv in ${services[*]}; do
        echo "Starting service $serv"
        systemctl start $serv
    done

    for port in ${ports[*]}; do
        echo "Opening port $port"
        ufw allow $port &> /dev/null
    done
}

# Stops the services and closes the ports
finish() {
    for serv in ${services[*]}; do
        echo "Stopping service $serv"
        systemctl stop $serv
    done

    for port in ${ports[*]}; do
        echo "Closing port $port"
        ufw deny $port &> /dev/null
    done
}

# Catch ^c and terminal close signals:
trap finish 0

start

echo
echo "Awaiting interruption..."
echo

while :; do
    read -t 1 -n 1 -s PASSWORD
    if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
        break
    fi
done
```

I'm looking for feedback, mainly to see if I could improve this productive waste of time.

The new things I learned by doing this script were:

- The parsing of options (-s and -p) with `case ... in` and `shift`;
- The use of `trap`;
- The "press key to continue" loop.

The only caveat I found was that even though I use `trap` to detect when the script dies it does not work if the terminal it runs on closes, leaving the services started. It doesn't work either if the signal I trap are `SIGINT` and `SIGCHLD`.

Thanks for reading.